# What is the most efficient way to store a char pointer into a string in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the most effective way to store a char pointer into a string in C++?

Comment: What do you mean store a char pointer into a string?  Do you mean create an STL string from a C string?

Comment: Sure. I have a character pointer that I would like to identify as a string.

Comment: and embrace www.cplusplus.com for what it's worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::string` class has an appropriate constructor that takes a `const char *` argument:

```
const char *p = "hello world";
std::string s = std::string(p);
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

That will print

```
hello world
```

Comment: DO I need to include 'std::' if I state using namespace std?

Comment: Why `std::string s = std::string(p);`? why not simply `std::string s(p);`?

Comment: @idealistikz: Correct, if you have a `using namespace std;` then writing `std::` is not required.

Comment: @Nawaz: `std::string s(p);` is perfectly valid as well as `std::string s = p;`. I just wanted to draw specific attention to the *constructor* call, those three ways of writing the initialisation are all equivalent.

Comment: @GregHewgill: They're not exactly equivalent. For example, if the copy-semantic of the class is disabled, then `std::string s = std::string(p);` and `std::string s = p;` both will fail to compile, but `std::string s(p);` will work even then. You can say that in this particular case, they all will emit the same machine code.

Comment: @Nawaz: in C++03 and in particular in current Visual C++, writing `T x { values }` is not supported, while the old C syntax `T x = { values }` is, of course, supported. I also find it more clear with the `=` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Basically one of the string constructors is

```
string (const char* s);
```

which builds a string using a constant character pointer. This means that you can implicit cast a `const char*` to string like

```
const char* cstr = "Hello, World!";
std::string cppStr = cstr;
```

Any try to implicitly or explicitly cast a `const char*` to `std::string` is viable; for instance

```
cppStr = cppStr + cstr;
```

Or you could just call the constructor and pass the parameters

```
std::string cppstr2 {cstr};
```

If you have a `constexpr` it would be a string literal and most compilers convert string literal into `std::string` at compile time making its time complexity constant. However converting a constant pointer or a conventional c_string to a `std::string` takes linear time.

More info on
[std::string](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)